# How to use bootstrap modal-dialog in django?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, django-views

I am having a problem in using bootstrap modal-dialog in my Django template. When a user submits the form then the modal-dialog appear only for 2 seconds and redirect to the index.html file.

This is my views.py file

```
class RequestItem(generic.CreateView):
model = UserNotification
fields = ['Name', 'Mobile_No', 'Proof']

def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    if form_class is None:
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['Name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '*Enter your name'})
    form.fields['Mobile_No'].widget = TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': "*Enter your's mobile number to get a call back from angel"})
    form.fields['Proof'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '*enter proof you have for your lost item'})
    return form

def form_valid(self, form):
    print(self.kwargs)

    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    qs = Report_item.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
    self.object.user = qs[0].owner
    self.object.save()
    query_list = Report_item.objects.filter(publish=True)
    return render(self.request,"feed/index.html",{"object_list":query_list})
```

This is my form with the modal-dialog:

```html
<div class="thumbnail" style="padding-right:5%;">
        <div class="thumbnail-center">
            <font size="6">
            <p>Please fill this form</p>
            </font>
        </div>
        <form class="form-herizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
              {% if form.errors %}
                <p>{{ form.errors }}</p>
              {% endif %}
            {% include 'feed/form_template.html'%}
            <br>
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <button type="submit" class="login-btn btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Request to return</button>
                        {% else %}
                            <button type="submit" class="login-btn btn btn-success" disabled>Request to return</button>
                            <p style="color:red;">*Please <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>to request yout item</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>


                </div>

            <br>

        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Request Done</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Your request has been done.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want that the user only redirects to index page when clicked the close button of the modal-dialog. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have the modal in the same page as the form, and it is triggered by the **submit** button, so the form does what it is meant to do: **post to the server**. The modal **doesn't stop this action**. Even more, it is a *success* message, so it should appear *after* the form is sent and return a response, which in your case is render the index page.

What you can do is, instead of render the index when success, is to render a page with the modal, triggered on load, that can perform the actions you need.

Comment: You got te error. Thanks for it. This is a nice idea but I can not do that because index page is common to more pages but I need to show this modal only for one form.

Comment: @imsaiful Yes, what I'm proposing is that. After the form is posted you response with a modal, not the index. So it only shows in that specific case.